# EF6 code-first: access to database before update database

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to create a project with EF6.1 with code-first. All works fine I have migration is enabled, create and update DB works too. Now my Problem:
I have create a table "VersionHistory" and a CompanyInfo table.

I'm writing an "Upgrade Wizzard" for update the database. Is it possible to get data from this tables to Display Information (e.g. YourCompanyName and Update from Program Version 1.x to 1.y) before I start the database update?

Should I use classic SQLConnection for this?

Many thanks

Comment: Why not put this info to configuration file?

Comment: it is a multi user invironment and one user/admin have the rights to upgrade the database and rollout the new program files.

Comment: Why not just use EF? If you want to keep it out of your DbSets - use a stored procedure or view.

Comment: @Steve: I wish a can use EF, but I get the Error "Model backing changed, use update...".  I have "Chicken-Egg-Problem" I will get Information from a VersionHistory tabel from Database, but I can not access on DB while the model is changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SQL Connection (it can be the same of EF) or you can disable EF database structure checking.

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<MyModel>(null);
```

**EDIT**

If you access to an entity that is not updated on the database, you can receive Ado exceptions from EF (i.e. missing columns, missing tables and so on).

Comment: this i have tried in the ctor from my AppContext, before using ever with the same exception:

Comment: This I have tried in the ctor from my AppContext, before using ever with the same exception:

in ctor<!-- language: c# -->
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<AppContext>(null);
Using(var ctx = new AppContext()){
 var version = ctx.Versions.LastOrDefault() -> exception
}

Exception:
Invalid column name 'Servername'.
Invalid column name 'ConnectionType'.
Invalid column name 'IntegratedSecurity'.

Comment: The exception seems not to be related to the model. It seems related to some missing columns in table. If you don't check the model and your model is not up to date you can have this exception when you access to the part of the model that is not updated. I also updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In compliance with "bubi" I will use a SQLConnection based on my Context e.g.

```
using (var ctx = new AppContext()) {
ctx.Database.Connection.Open();

var cmd = ctx.Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Select * From CompanyInfo";

var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
var infos = (from row in rdr.Cast<System.Data.Common.DbDataRecord>()

             let entityId = (int)row["EntityId"] //internal key
             let entityKey = (string)row["EntityKey"] //visible key
             let displayname = (string)row["DisplayName"] //company name

             // some more stuff (version, etc.)

             select new NOCompanyInfo {
                 EntityId = entityId,
                 EntityKey = entityKey,
                 DisplayName = displayname,
                 DBName = dbName,
                 ...
             }).ToList();

return new ObservableCollection<NOCompanyInfo>(infos);
```

}

Thanks